# Catch ImportError but don't catch nested import errors

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

**The questions:**

1. Is there a robust way to distinguish the import error of the current call to `__import__` from the nested import errors?
2. Is there another robust way to check the module existense and accessibility except of `try` statement?

**The story:**

I've found this code in `python2.7/unittest/loader.py`.

```
parts = name.split('.')
if module is None:
    parts_copy = parts[:]
    while parts_copy:
        try:
            module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
            break
        except ImportError:
            del parts_copy[-1]
            if not parts_copy:
                raise
```

It tries to import module by it's `name`. If failed then it removes the last part from the list of `parts` and tries again, until the list is empty.

The code relies on the `ImportError` exception. It is based on assumption that the exception means the specified `name` is not a module name, but a name of some object in that module (maybe function or class).

The problem is that the `ImportError` exception may be raised by a nested import including my own modules. If so, I'd not like to have this error be suppressed and handled as a normal situation by this code. I want to know why my code does not work without deep dive into the library source code. But this kind of problems makes it hard and wastes the developer's time. I'd like to propose a change to this library, but I'm not sure what is the good solution in this case.